# Should I use normalize.css with jquery mobile?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

Any harm/drawbacks to using normalize.css with jquery-mobile's default theme/css file?

The developers on my project have included the file out of habit but I'm thinking jquery-mobile already does what normalize.css is meant (make browsers render consistently) with their default styles

Are the declarations going to be redundant and just add weight to the page.

If there is some point for using normalize.css along with jquery-mobile styles, should I include normalize first or jquery-mobile?

Comment: You will not doubt have certain styles that over write each other with these two files depending on in what order they are included.  To that extent...  If you include jquery-mobile and then normalize.css normalize will overwrite any duplicate styles from jquery-mobile.  The opposite is true if normalize.css comes first.  When a page loads it reads code left to right and top to bottom, so whatever happens last is what it is going to use.  If you make a <p> tag have width:200px in jquery-mobile and width:300px in normalize, and normalize comes last, then the p will be 300px wide.  (for example)

Answer (score 0):

Hello Vincent It is a very good question (+1) I have the same question. I will tell you that after looking at jQuery mobile's css I have found out that it does not include reset.css or normalize.css , and if you include these files, before the jquery mobile css it will help to ensure that your project will look alike across all devices,

However since jQuery mobile is for mobile devices considering the fact that these devices do not have the unqiue, and proprietary default user agent styles and follow a rather similar default stylesheet (as they have been all built mainly when using these design methods were a must, and default css was proven to create browser incompatibility issues) therefore not including a normalize.css file will not really make that much of a difference however it will make certain changes if you compare the two in pixel perfection.

I myself have decided that for my project I will not use these files, and write a very custom normalize css specially having to do with font sizes.

If you would like to have a site with pixel perfection I think you should use an approach like reset.css instead of normalize.css as jquery mobile will styles everything it needs so everything will look like as they should and the very few exceptions will all be the same in all devices as they have been reset by you manually, the advantage of reset.css is that I beleive it is smaller in size, however perhaps expensive to render if you apply it to everything using wildcards `* { /*code*/ }`.

Just remember that if you have a lot of  customization to the jQM UI itseelt than you will need to either test it thoroughly or have to use normalize.css